# Why isn't 'menuBtn.addEventListner' a function?

Tags: javascript, methods

```
const menuBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".menu-btn")

menuBtn.forEach(function(btn) {
    btn.addEventListener("click", function(e){
        let menuID = e.currentTarget.dataset.id;
    })
})

menuBtn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    let menuID = e.currentTarget.dataset.id;
})
```

Here is a question. Why isn't 'menuBtn.addEventListner' a function?
Why is the second one wrong?

Thanks for your kind explanation :)

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll(...)` returns a [collection of elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), not a single element on which you can call the method. You can iterate over the collection returned by `document.querySelectorAll(...)` and add an event listener on each element in the collection or take advantage of [event bubbling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_bubbling_and_capture) and just add a single event listener on the common parent element.

Comment: menuBtn is a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), If you have a single button then it's better to use an ID instead of a class then you can select it using `document.getElementById('menu-btn');` or `document.querySelector('#menu-btn');`

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event listener to a single node/button, not an array of buttons. That's Why we use the second one is wrong.:)

This one can also help you
https://www.nickang.com/2018-03-06-add-event-listener-for-loop-problem-in-javascript/

Comment: Please include the answer as text. Links can go dead, then this answer wouldn't be helpful to anyone